# Cannot find a simple integral with Pascal

Tags: integration, pascal, type-conversion, freepascal, turbo-pascal

I've written a programm to solve the integral X^2+2 by rectangles method

```
program fourrr;

var    a, b : real; { borders }
       h : real; { increment argument }
       s : real; { approximate value of the integral }
       n : integer; { number of intervals }
       x : real; { argument }
       y : real; { function value at the beginning of interval }
       i : integer;
begin

    write('lower border a: '); read(a);
    write('upper border b: '); read(b);
    write('increment argument h: '); read(h);

     n := (b - a) / (h + 1);
     x := a;
     s := 0;

    i := 1;
    while i <= n do
      begin
        y := x * x + 2;   // function value at the beginning of interval
        s := s + (y * h);
        x := x + h;
      end;

   writeln('Integral value: ', s); 
end.
```

but i cannot solve the problem with data types conversion when I run it.

So please help me it's very important. Thanks

Comment: For starters you might think about changing at least one of the elements in the loop termination condition within the loop.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What does "the problem with data types conversion" mean? In what way is the code not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

(Since the beginning, sorry for my bad english)

At the beginning, you need the input output:
program fourrr(input,output);

I see that you done    n := (b - a) / (h + 1);
And that's not / , you should use " div " :
n := (b - a) div (h + 1);

I don't know why did you use the loop ,and I tell you that I don't know how to solve that integral,but, if it's as you did, you don't need it.
What you could change in the loop?
Using the IF.

{ `If i<=n THEN 
  Begin
    y:=x * x + 2;   // function value at the beginning of interval
    s := s + (y * h);
    x := x + h; 
  end   (*without the ; simbol*)
 Else
    writeln('ERROR'); (*The ELSE only read for him the writeln('error'), if you want to use more things , use the ELSE begin h:= ... ; alpha:=... If ...(<-for example) end;*)`}

Comment: "At the beginning" is wrong; the program prompts the user for each input with `write`, and then reads the response from the console. You don't need any `program fourrr(input, output)`, because it's not getting the values as command line parameters.

Comment: Your advice: _And that's not / , you should use " div " : n := (b - a) div (h + 1);_ is wrong (even worse) and will 
produce another error because you **cannot** use  `div` with floating point data types. Correct would be
`n := round((b - a) / (h + 1));`